# $x^3 + y^3 +3x^2 y^2 =x^3y^3$ Find all possible values to $\frac{x+y}{xy}$

Tags: contest-math

$x,y \in \mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$

Indeed the original question said :Find all possible values to: $$\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y}$$
But it’s the same thing.

**My Attempt:**
$$x^3 + y^3 +3x^2 y^2 =x^3y^3 \iff (x+y)(x^2-xy+y^2)=x^3y^3 -3x^2y^2$$
$$\frac{x+y}{xy}=\frac{x^2y^2-3xy}{x^2-xy+y^2}$$

But i don’t know what to do now.
Please if you know the key to this type of problems ‘Find all possible values’ post it.

Comment: If it helps Wolfram Alpha says the only real solutions are $(x,y) \in \{(-1,\frac12),(-1,-1),(2,2)\}$

Comment: @Mastermind That is odd because there appear to be more than these, e.g. $(3,\frac{3}{2}), (\frac{4}{3}, 4)$.

Comment: My first comment are the real solutions to $x^3+y^3+3x^2y^2=x^3y^3$

Comment: I edited my answer because I discovered a new solution thanks to the comment of @MartinR

Comment: @Mastermind817: All $(x, y) = (1/p, 1/q)$ with $p+q=1$ are solutions of the equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x^3 + y^3 + 3 x^2 y^2 = x^3 y^3\tag{1}$$
$$\frac{x+y}{xy}\tag{2}$$
$$x^3 + y^3 + 3 x^2 y^2 - x^3 y^3=0$$
can be factorized$^1$ as
$$(x+y-xy) \left(x^2 y^2+x^2 y+x^2+x y^2-x y+y^2\right)=0$$
$x^2 y^2+x^2 y+x^2+x y^2-x y+y^2=0$ has solution$^2$ given by $x=y=-1$ we have $$\frac{x+y}{xy}=-2$$, the solutions of $(1)$ are only those of $x+y-xy=0$ that is $x+y=xy$ and finally
$$\frac{x+y}{xy}=1$$

---

$(^1)$

$$x^3 + y^3 + 3 x^2 y^2 - x^3 y^3=(x+y)^3-3x^2y-3xy^2+ 3 x^2 y^2 - x^3 y^3=$$
$$=\left[(x+y)^3- x^3 y^3\right]+\left[-3x^2y-3xy^2+ 3 x^2 y^2 \right]=$$
$$=(x+y-xy)\left[(x+y)^2+xy(x+y)+x^2y^2)\right]-3 x y (x+y-x y)=$$
$$=(x+y-xy)\left[(x+y)^2+xy(x+y)+x^2y^2)-3xy\right]=(x+y-xy)\left(x^2 y^2+x^2 y+x^2+x y^2-x y+y^2\right)$$

$(^2)$

$$x^2 y^2+x^2 y+x^2+x y^2-x y+y^2=0$$
set $y=kx$. We get
$$k^2 x^4+k^2 x^3+k^2 x^2+k x^3-k x^2+x^2=0\to x^2 \left(k^2 x^2+k^2 x+k x+k^2-k+1\right)=0$$
As $x\ne 0$ we have
$$k^2 x^2+k^2 x+k x+k^2-k+1=0$$
the discriminant of this equation is $D=-k^4+2 k^3-k^2=-k^2(k-1)^2$

$D\ge 0\to k=1 $ (solution $k=0$ is discarded)

if $k=1$ we have $x^2+2x+1=0\to x=-1$ thus the solutions are
$$x=-1;\;y=-1$$

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, $x^3 + y^3 + 3 x^2 y^2 = x^3 y^3$ has also the solution $x=y=-1$, and that gives $\frac{x+y}{xy}=-2$.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I am looking for a way to prove it @MartinR

Answer (score 4):

Because $x,y \ne 0$, from $x^3 + y^3 +3x^2 y^2 =x^3y^3$, we have
$$\frac{1}{x^3}+\frac{1}{y^3} +\frac{3}{xy} =1 \iff\frac{1}{x^3}+\frac{1}{y^3}  =1-\frac{3}{xy} \tag{1}$$
But we have also

$$(\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y})^3 = (\frac{1}{x^3}+\frac{1}{y^3}) + \frac{3}{xy}(\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}) \tag{2}$$
From (1) and (2), we deduce
\begin{align}
&(\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y})^3 = (1-\frac{3}{xy}) + \frac{3}{xy}(\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}) \\
&\iff (\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y})^3- 1=\frac{3}{xy}\left( \frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y} - 1  \right) \\
&\iff \left( \frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y} - 1  \right)\left( (\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y})^2 +(\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y})+1   \right)=\frac{3}{xy}\left( \frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y} - 1  \right) \\
&\iff \left( \frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y} - 1  \right)\left( (\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y})^2 +(\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y})+1  -\frac{3}{xy} \right)=0\\
&\iff \left( \frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y} - 1  \right)\left( (\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y})^2 -\frac{4}{xy} +(\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y})+1 +\frac{1}{xy}   \right)=0\\
&\iff \left( \frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y} - 1  \right)\left( (\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{y})^2  +\left( 1+\frac{1}{x}   \right)\left( 1+\frac{1}{y} \right)  \right)  =0\\
&\iff \left( \frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y} - 1  \right)\left( ((1+\frac{1}{x})-(1+\frac{1}{y}))^2  +\left( 1+\frac{1}{x}   \right)\left( 1+\frac{1}{y} \right)  \right)  =0\\
&\iff \left( \frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y} - 1  \right)\left( \left(1+\frac{1}{x} \right)^2+\left(1+\frac{1}{y} \right)^2  -\left( 1+\frac{1}{x}   \right)\left( 1+\frac{1}{y} \right)  \right)  =0\\
\end{align}

The last equation happens if and only if $\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y} =1$  or $\left( 1+\frac{1}{x}, 1+\frac{1}{y} \right) = (0,0) $. Hence, the two possible values of $\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}$ is $1$ and $-2$.

Comment: How did you move from the first equation to the second

Comment: You can replace $\frac{1}{x^3}+\frac{1}{y^3} $ by $1-\frac{3}{xy}$ in the second equation

Comment: Is there a mis-step in saying $(\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y})^2 +(\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y})+1-\frac{3}{xy}=((\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{y})^2 +(1+\frac{1}{x})(1+\frac{1}{y}))$.  I seem to be missing something.

Comment: @WADon: no, you have:  $(\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y})^2 -\frac{4}{xy} = (\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{y})^2$ and $(\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y})+1 +\frac{1}{xy} = (1+\frac{1}{x})(1+\frac{1}{y})$

Comment: Oh yes, thanks!

Comment: If $\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}=-2$ then $y=-\frac{x}{2 x+1}$ and $$x^3+3 x^2 y^2+y^3=x^3 y^3$$ is not satisfied

Comment: @Raffaele: No, $x=y=-1$ (because $\left( 1+\frac{1}{x}, 1+\frac{1}{y} \right) = (0,0) $). So, we deduce $\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y} = -2$. But you don't have $y = -\frac{x}{2x+1}$ for all $x$ here

Comment: @NN2: One can shorten the calculation a bit by introducing $s=1/x+1/y$ and $p=1/(xy)$. Then $0=s^3 -3ps+3p-1=(s-1)(s^2+s-3p+1)$. The second factor is $\ge s^2+s-3p/4+1 = (s+2)^2/4$ because of AM-GM, so it becomes zero only for $s=-2$.

Comment: @MartinR: I agree.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Let $\dfrac{x+y}{xy}=k$

$$(xy)^3=3(xy)^2+(x+y)^3-3xy(x+y)$$

$$\iff(xy)^3(1-k^3)-3(xy)^2+3xy(kxy)=0$$

$$\iff(xy)^3(1-k^3)+3(xy)^2(k-1)=0$$

As $xy\ne0$ $$(xy)(1-k^3)=3(1-k)$$

Clearly, $k=1$ is a solution.

Otherwise,  $$xy=\dfrac3{1+k+k^2}$$

Comment: can you explain what happened in the second equation, after you've set $$\frac{x+y}{xy}=k$$

Comment: @Yassir, I have replaced  $x+y$ with $kxy$

Comment: $k = 1$ is the only solution? @lab bhattacharjee

Answer (score 1):

The following is equivalent to @NN2's solution, only written a bit differently.

First substitute $x=1/a, y=1/b$, so that the equation becomes
$$ \tag{*}
 a^3+b^3+3ab - 1 = 0 \, .
$$
We are looking for the possible values of $a+b$, this suggests to introduce $S=a+b$ and $P = ab$. Then
$$
 0 = a^3+b^3+3ab - 1 = S^3+3PS + 3P -1 = (S-1)(S^2 + S-3P+1) \, .
$$

So $S=1$ is one possible value for $a+b$. Conversely, all $(a, b)$ with $a+b=1$ satisfy the equation $(*)$.

In order to determine the possible zeros of the second factor we use that $P \le S^2/4$ from the inequality between geometric and arithmethic mean:
$$
0 = S^2 + S-3P+1 \ge S^2 + S-\frac 34 S^2+1 = \frac 14 (S+2)^2 \ge 0
$$
is only possible if $S=-2$ and $P=1$, i.e. if $(a, b) = (-1, -1)$.

Therefore $S=a+b=1/x+1/y$ can only take the values $1$ and $-2$, and both values do actually occur.